# How to quit or exit evcxr in Rust without ctrl-c'ing?

Tags: rust, read-eval-print-loop, evcxr

Simple question, but how can i exit or quit Rust's REPL tool called evcxr?

I tried `quit()`, `exit()`, `:q` and ran out of ideas after that.

Well I can always do `ctrl-c` of course, but I was wondering if there is an actual command for it.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, the way to quit evcxr is:
`:quit`

Found the answer here:
https://github.com/evcxr/evcxr/blob/main/COMMON.md